# MySQL transpose columns sum into rows with column names as a value

Tags: mysql

MySQL table is as follows

```
A | B1|B2|
-----------
0 | 1 |1 |
1 | 0 |1 |
1 | 0 |1 |
1 | 0 |0 |
```

I need to transpose my data in a table which contains only 2 columns: labels and sum of the original column contents such as

```
codes | sums
------------
A     | 3
B1    | 1
B2    | 3
```

I don't handle very much MySQL syntax and I don't find the proper query. I can get the sum of the column, but I still don't understand how to transpose the column's name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a possible solution:

```
SELECT 'A' as `codes`, SUM(`A`) as `sums` FROM `your_table_name`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1' as `codes`, SUM(`B1`) as `sums` FROM `your_table_name`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B2' as `codes`, SUM(`B2`) as `sums` FROM `your_table_name`
```